# Why does adding a subplot to a matplotlib figure cause numpy to crash?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, pyqt5

I made a dialog window in QtDesigner that contains a widget that contains a layout named `plot_layout` .

When running this code, Numpy executes with no issue: Please note that `self.ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)` is commented out.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import join
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar


dir = Path(os.getcwd())
parent_dir = os.path.normpath(dir.parent)
sys.path.append(parent_dir)

class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi(join(parent_dir, r'sub_windows\test.ui'), self)

        fig1 = Figure()
        # self.ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
        canvas1 = FigureCanvas(fig1)
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(canvas1)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar(canvas1, self.widget, coordinates=True)
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(toolbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.action)

    def action(self):
        c = np.polyfit(np.arange(1600), np.arange(1600) + 1, deg=1)
        print(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Test()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, after uncommenting `self.ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)`, this error occurs:

```
** On entry to DLASCLS parameter number  4 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DLASCLS parameter number  4 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DLASCLS parameter number  4 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DLASCLS parameter number  4 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DLASCLS parameter number  5 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DLASCLS parameter number  4 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in action
    c = np.polyfit(np.arange(1600), np.arange(1600) + 1, deg=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in polyfit
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 629, in polyfit
    c, resids, rank, s = lstsq(lhs, rhs, rcond)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in lstsq
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2306, in lstsq
    x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 100, in _raise_linalgerror_lstsq
    raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

I've tried this same exact code on two other computers running the same version of python, and it ran without issue.  Any suggestions on how to diagnose this on my current system?  I'm running Python 3.7.8 64-bit, Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, all packages are the latest versions, Intel Core i5-8400.  Note: I've also tried reinstalling python and even installing python 3.8, but all had the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in numpy. Your problem could be the `np.polyfit` that appears incompatible with certain `matplotlib` charts. Even replacing it with `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit` will not help.

In my case, I solved this problem by replacing this function with my own least-squares linear regression fit:

```
def linreg(x, y):
   meanx = np.mean(x)
   meany = np.mean(y)
   sumxx2 = np.sum((x - meanx) ** 2)
   sumxy = np.sum(((x - meanx) * (y - meany)))
   m = sumxy / sumxx2
   c = meany - m * meanx
   return np.array([c, m])  # though, you might want to return as np.array([m, c]) as np.polyfit would
```

Also see: [Python: creating plot causes future numpy.linalg.ein to diverge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63339726/7051064)

Comment: Windows 2004 update could also be the problem. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16744

Comment: Windows 2004 may very well be the problem.  I discovered that the system was recently updated to Windows 2004 a few days ago, around the same time this issue arose.  Also, the other two systems running earlier versions of Windows 10 don't have this issue with numpy.

Comment: Did you at least try replacing the np.polyfit to see if this problem persists?

Comment: Yes, the problem still persists even with np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit().  I ended up writing my own linreg function as you suggested.